# Regex remove alphabets

Tags: java, regex, string

I am having the below value in my index.

```
index = ACCOUNT_M1_4_0
```

I need to remove the continuous alphabets alone & the M1 should not be removed.
In this case i tried to use the below format

```
String test = index.replaceAll("[A-Z]+", "");
```

But the output of string test is `_1_4_0`

How to remove the continuous alphabet alone in regex?

Comment: try `String test = index.replaceAll("^[A-Z]+", "");`

Comment: or `String test = index.replaceAll("(?<=^|_)[A-Z]+(?=_|$)", "");`

Comment: Or `replaceAll("[A-Z]+_", "")` will give you `M1_4_0`. I believe you don't want `_M1_4_0`

Comment: What would be an expected output for `ACCOUNT_M1_TEXT_4_0`? `M1_TEXT_4_0` or `M1_4_0`?

Comment: Thanks Avinash !. It works fine with both the mentioned outputs..

Comment: Many thanks Vinod, The excepted output is M1_4_0. Thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: Hello stribizhev. got output from Vinod & Avinash reply. Thnxx

Answer (score 1):

Solutions proposed by [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) and [Vinod Madyalkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193767/vinod-madyalkar) that helped out OP:

#### Option 1

```
String test = index.replaceAll("^[A-Z]+", "");
```

#### Option 2

```
String test = index.replaceAll("(?<=^|_)[A-Z]+(?=_|$)", "");
```

#### Option 3

```
String test = index.replaceAll("[A-Z]+_", "");
```

---

IMO, Option 2 is the more appropriate.

[image: Regular expression visualization]